How to solve for the critical points of $f(x) = 3x - \tan(x)?$
I've been trying for quite a while now to try and solve the problem:

The function $f(x) = 3x - \tan(x)$ has two critical points in the interval $\pi/2 < x < \pi/2$. Find the x-coordinates of the extrema's.


My attempt:
$ f(x) = 3x - \tan(x)$
I took the derivative:
$f'(x) = 3 - \frac{(\cos^2x + \sin^2(x))}{\cos^2(x)}$
Set the derivative function to zero:
$0 = 3 - \frac{1}{\cos^2(x)} \iff$
$\cos(x) = \pm\sqrt\frac{1}{3} \iff $
$x = \arccos(\pm\sqrt\frac{1}{3})$

The only problem now is that, when I take the negative root, I do not match up with the real answer. The real answer is approximately $-0.9553$, meaning taking the negative of the first root. It perfectly makes sense graphically, I have done that on Desmos. However, computationally, it is not really matching up.
Could someone please explain how to solve the problem computationally without the error I made. It would be sincerely appreciated. Thank you!

$\cos y=z$ is not the same as $z=\arccos y.$ In particular, $\arccos y$ is usually in $[0,\pi],$ while you want your angle in a different range. And the range you want for $x$ means $\cos x$ is always positive.

The inverse cosine will never be in the interval if the object of the inverse cosine is negative.  But cosine is not injective.  So, perhaps there is another value such that $\cos a = \sqrt {\frac 13}$ yet $a\ne \arccos \sqrt {\frac 13}$

You've forgotten that you want $x\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2),$ so the negative square root is irrelevant, since $\cos x$ is positive in that interval.
On the other hand $\cos x=1/\sqrt3$ does not imply $x=\arccos(1/\sqrt3),$ since $\cos(-\theta)=\cos(\theta).$
So the real solution is $x=\pm\arccos(1/\sqrt3).$

$x=\pm\arccos(-1/\sqrt3)$ are critical points, but the question asks for the critical points $x\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2),$ and these two critical points are outside that interval.

Notice that $\cos(x)$ is an even function and $\cos x$ doesn't take negative value in the range between $-\frac{\pi}2$ and $\frac{\pi}2$.
The two solutions are symmetrical about the $y$-axis, they are $\pm \arccos \frac1{\sqrt3}$
